# How to load my local mpd(mpeg-dash) file to online players?

Tags: url, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am trying to use some online players to test my local mpd file, but it could't be loaded as 'file:///path-to-file' form like local urls, what's the correct format to load the file? Or should I upload it online or so?

Answer (score 1):

DASH is designed to be streamed from a server so the player will be expecting to send requests for the mpd and for each media chunk to a server which will respond with the mpd or corresponding chunk.

The mpd is the 'index file' or manifest for the individual video and audio streams.

If you want to test locally then this is definitely possible and the easiest way is to set up a local test server and stream from there. You will need to create the mpd and the chunked media streams and make them available on your server, but it sounds like you have already these created.

You can then point your test player to your local server. Remember to ensure the server serves the streams using HTTPS as this is required by most players and browsers now.

There are a good set of step by step instructions available from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video